# android how to check if service is running

Tags: android, service, gps

I have an app that gets GPS co-ordinates. It works fine but i want to test from within the calling activity if the service is running. I have the following code that i thought would check but it is returning false when the GPS icon in the notification bar is still flashing. Has anyone any ideas why? Thanks in advance

```
private boolean isGpsServiceRunning() {
          ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
          for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if ("LocationService".equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
              return true;
            }
          }
          return false;
        }
```

.

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
                            .registerReceiver(
                                    locationChangereceiver,
                                    new IntentFilter(
                                            LocationChangeIntent.ACTION_LOCATION_CHANGE));
                    startService(new Intent(this, LocationService.class));
```

Comment: Does it ever return true? Did you try to print all the running services just to verify that you are not looking for the wrong value. Also, I would suggest using LocationService.class.getSimpleName() instead of hard coding it.

Comment: just fixed it, i needed to put the package name in as well. The same as what you're saying. create an answer and i'll accept. thanks

Comment: (ActivityManager)getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE); <--- compare that with my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should compare against `LocationService.class.getName()`, instead of using a hard coded value. Also, the value that you are using corresponds to the [Class#getSimpleName()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class.html#getSimpleName%28%29) which is probably not what you want here.

Answer (score 2):

```
 public boolean check(){
     ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) 
            {
                if ("com.example.yourpackagename.YourserviceName"
                        .equals(service.service.getClassName())) 
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
         return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

this method works fine for me and is easy to use:

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

    Log.i(TAG,"MyService.class.getName() = "+ButtonOnBootService.class.getName());              

    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {

        Log.i(TAG,"service.getClassName() = " +service.service.getClassName());

        if (ButtonOnBootService.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;   
}
```

Comment: You might want to add a check like this: service.uid == Process.myUid(). This will speed-up the search and avoid finding the service in another process, even though unlikely I got this issue running the same app free/paid version simultaneously!

Comment: thanks. i will look into it. speeding up android in any way sounds useful :-)